# Unable to fetch Postgres records where date is 0001-01-01 BC using Pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, postgresql

I have a PostgreSQL 11 database which for some reason holds some records such as:

```sql
database=> SELECT id, date_one, date_two, date_three FROM mytable WHERE id = 1337;

   id   | date_one   |   date_two    |   date_three    
--------+------------+---------------+---------------
 1337   | 1934-06-24 | 0001-01-01 BC | 0001-01-01 BC
(1 row)
```

And when I try to fetch these records, I got an error:

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_sql('select id, date_one, date_two, date_three from mytable where id = 1337;',
    connector_DB()
)
```

yields:

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-72-08b82cbc2885>", line 1, in <module>
    df = pd.read_sql('select id, date_one, date_two, date_three from mytable where id = 1337;', connector_DB())

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pandas/io/sql.py", line 489, in read_sql
    chunksize=chunksize,

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pandas/io/sql.py", line 1740, in read_query
    data = self._fetchall_as_list(cursor)

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pandas/io/sql.py", line 1753, in _fetchall_as_list
    result = cur.fetchall()

ValueError: year 0 is out of range
```

Can someome kindly explain me what exactly is wrong there? Because I found (many) people speaking about this bug when the date is 0000-00-00 or something similar, but my date is actually a valid date, isn't it? So I don't get it. And how could I avoid this error?

My Pandas version is '1.1.4' and Python 3.6.9 (default, Jan 26 2021, 15:33:00).

Comment: I ran into this error last week. Is the date in your postgres actually 0-0-1 BC? or is it some other date that has just been interpreted incorrectly by postgres? If it is the latter, you should be able to strftime in postgres and let pandas interpret the datetime

Comment: Well, the date actually pops exactly as shown in the sql query results display in the first table of the OP. Is there anything else I can do to print out more details? And pgAdmin tells me the format of all these colums is simply `date`.

Comment: Try [using `to_char(...)` to turn the date into some sort of string](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/functions-formatting.html), which you can later parse in pandas

Comment: Hmm, nope: `No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.`

Comment: `select to_char('0001-01-01 BC' :: date, 'YYYY-MM-DD')` gives me `0001-01-01` as text. What am I missing?

Comment: Because I didn't type-casted it. The query you wrote is working. But I'll check if I can get a fix on the DB itself, it will be much cleaner imho. Otherwise I have to transform the string as a valid datetime object in Python using `datetime.datetime.strptime(<date-as-a-string>, '%Y-%m-%d')` with `<date-as-a-string>` object being e.g. `'0001-01-01'`. This will lead to a valid Python `datetime.datetime(1, 1, 1, 0, 0)` object.

Comment: You could use the DB's date-as-string to parse it back into a date-as-date within postgres and then pull it back as a datetime into pd

Comment: If you can come up with a simple reproducible test case, report it as a psycopg2 bug.